# Dukt twitter issue Craft 2.5

Tags: plugin-dukttwitter

Weird issue when upgrading Craft to 2.5 that the settings link in the revised dashboard redirects to the settings page for the Dukt twitter add-on. If I disable the add-on then works just fine. Anybody else experiencing this problem?

Answer (score 2):

While we wait for an official update, you can patch this pretty easily. Just open up craft/plugins/twitter/TwitterPlugin.php and find this function:

```php
public function getSettingsHtml()
{
    // ...
}
```

Delete the function entirely, and replace it with this:

```php
public function getSettingsUrl()
{
    return 'twitter/settings';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually had to make this same change to the OAuth part of this plugin at craft/plugins/oauth/OauthPlugin.php

Comment: Are you on the latest versions? Could explain my recent issues